# If $a+b+c+d=0$ and $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset[-1,1]$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{1+a+b^2}\geq4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset[-1,1]$ such that $a+b+c+d=0$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{1+a+b^2}+\sqrt{1+b+c^2}+\sqrt{1+c+d^2}+\sqrt{1+d+a^2}\geq4$$
I tried Holder and more, but without success.

Comment: Wait a second, do you mean the interval $[-1,1]$ or they just can be either $1,-1$?

Comment: @ msm Yes, $a,b,c,d\in[-1,1]$. Id est, $-1\leq a,b,c,d\leq1$

Comment: I don't know exactly but does this have anything to do with AM-GM relationship ?

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts**

(For 3-variable problem, see: [Prove $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{34x^2 + 28y^2 + 7z^2 - xy - 28yz + 41zx} \ge 9x + 9y + 9z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877868/prove-sum-mathrmcyc-sqrt34x2-28y2-7z2-xy-28yz-41zx-ge-9x))

It suffices to prove the following:

**Problem 1**: Let $a, b, c, d \ge -1$ with $a+b+c+d = 0$. Prove that
$$\sqrt{1 + a + b^2} + \sqrt{1 + b + c^2} + \sqrt{1 + c + d^2} + \sqrt{1 + d + a^2} \ge 4.$$
(Thank @tthnew for verifying it by his routine.)

Problem 1 is equivalent to Problem 2 and Problem 3 below.

**Problem 2**: Let $x, y, z, w \ge 0$ with $x + y + z + w = 4$. Prove that
$$\sqrt{x + (y-1)^2} + \sqrt{y + (z-1)^2} + \sqrt{z + (w-1)^2} + \sqrt{w + (x-1)^2} \ge 4.$$

**Problem 3**: Let $x, y, z, w \ge 0$. Prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{5x^2 + 9y^2 + z^2 + w^2 - 2xy + 6xz + 6xw - 6yz - 6yw + 2zw} \ge 4(x+y+z+w).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ {x,y,z}\in[-1, 1]$,and $x+y+z=0 $

Prove: $$\sqrt{1+x+y^2}+\sqrt{1+y+z^2}+\sqrt{1+z+x^2}\geq 3$$
Proof:

First we will show:

If $ab\geq 0, $ then:$\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1+a}\geq 1+\sqrt{1+a+b}$

This is obvious！
Note that at least two of $ x+y^2, y+z^2 $ and $ z+x^2 $ have the same positive and negative values。Without loss of generality, we assume:$(x+y^2)(y+z^2)\geq 0$ then we have:$$\sqrt{1+x+y^2}+\sqrt{1+y+z^2}+\sqrt{1+z+x^2}$$ $$\geq 1+\sqrt{1+x+y^2+y+z^2}+\sqrt{1+z+x^2}$$ $$=1+\sqrt{(\sqrt{1-z+z^2})^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(\sqrt{1+z})^2+x^2}$$ $$\geq 1+\sqrt{(\sqrt{1-z+z^2}+\sqrt{1+z})^2+(x+y)^2}$$ $$ =1+\sqrt{(\sqrt{1-z+z^2}+\sqrt{1+z})^2+z^2}$$

So, just prove:$$(\sqrt{1-z+z^2}+\sqrt{1+z})^2+z^2\geq 4$$ $$\Longleftrightarrow 2z^2+2\sqrt{1+z^3}\geq 2$$ $$\Longleftrightarrow z^2(2-z)(z+1)\geq 0$$

This is clearly true because $|z|\leq 1$.Equal sign is established if and only if $x=y=z=0$

That's all,I hope it's works for you.

**PS**:Even if this method can be used, but the calculation is too complex that it is almost impossible to complete. The case of three variables is a good example, so I will not withdraw the answer.

Comment: It's the known Phan Thanh Nam's solution. See book of Pham Kim Hung "Secrets in Inequalities" (volume1), p158, n20. It does not help here.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  You are right, even if this method can be used, but the calculation is too complex that it is almost impossible to complete. The case of three variables is a good example, so I will not withdraw the answer.

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069951/if-abc-0-and-a-b-c-subset-1-1-so-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt1a-frac7 a stronger inequality