# If $a+b+c=0$ and $\{a,b,c\}\subset[-1,1]$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{1+a+\frac{7}{9}b^2}\geq3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a+b+c=0$ and $\{a,b,c\}\subset[-1,1]$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{1+a+\frac{7}{9}b^2}+\sqrt{1+b+\frac{7}{9}c^2}+\sqrt{1+c+\frac{7}{9}a^2}\geq3$$
I tried Holder and more, but without success.

Comment: you can plug $$c=-a-b$$ in the left hand side and consider a problem in two variables

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I tried. It's nothing.

Comment: i have found $$a=b=c=0$$ with my PC

Comment: or you use the Lagrange multiplier function

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I look for an human proof.

Comment: i'm also looking for such a proof

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: If $\sqrt{1+a+\frac{7}{9}b^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+b+\frac{7}{9}c^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+c+\frac{7}{9}a^2} = 1$, then the claim follows immediately.

Comment: @Moritz are you sure that $\prod\limits_{cyc}\left(1+a+\frac{7}{9}b^2\right)\geq1$ is true?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: No, I am not sure, that the product in your example really has the value 1 but IF you can show it to be true (exactly $=1$), then you are finished.

Comment: @Moritz i think you should take a look first what other inequalities the OP proposed, how many of them were solved, and the solutions of the solved ones :)

Comment: Where does this inequality come from?

Comment: @Piquito I think it was in AoPS.

Answer (score 0):

This one we can use [IntervalRootFinding.jl](https://juliaintervals.github.io/IntervalRootFinding.jl/latest/#IntervalRootFinding.jl-1), which "it guarantees to find all roots inside a given box".

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
f(a,b):=\sqrt{\frac{7 a^2}{9}-a-b+1}+\sqrt{a+\frac{7 b^2}{9}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{9} (-a-b)^2+b+1}-3 \ge 0.
$$ 
This not defined on the whole $T=[-1,1]^2$, but that's fine.

It's easy to check that $f(a,b)$ has a critical point at $(0,0)$. Using the following code, we can find all critical points of $f(a,b)$ in $T$ and we see that there is no minimal point inside $T$.

```
using IntervalArithmetic, IntervalRootFinding, ForwardDiff

f((a,b))=-3 + sqrt(1 - a + (7*a^2)/9 - b) + sqrt(
        1 + 7/9*(-a - b)^2 + b) + sqrt(1 + a + (7*b^2)/9)

∇f = ∇(f)

rts = roots(∇f, IntervalBox(-5..6, 2), Newton, 1e-5)

pt=interval.(rts)

println("The critical points")

println(pt)

println("The values at critical points")

println(f.(pt))
```

The output is

```
The critical points

IntervalBox{2,Float64}[[0.187395, 0.187396] × [0.665432, 0.665433], [0.665432, 0.665433] × [-0.852829, -0.852828], [-0.852829, -0.852828] × [0.187395, 0.187396], [-1.46504e-09, 1.46266e-09] × [-2.14219e-09, 2.13365e-09]]

The values at critical points

Interval{Float64}[[0.149065, 0.149067], [0.149065, 0.149066], [0.149065, 0.149066], [-3.60177e-09, 3.60177e-09]]
```

It remains to check the boundary of $T$, which is quite easy.