# Prove $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{34x^2 + 28y^2 + 7z^2 - xy - 28yz + 41zx} \ge 9x + 9y + 9z$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, buffalo-way

> **Problem 1**: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$. Prove that
> $$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{34x^2 + 28y^2 + 7z^2 - xy - 28yz + 41zx} \ge 9x + 9y + 9z. \tag{1}$$

**Background**: I came up with the problem when I tried to prove [If $a+b+c=0$ and $\{a,b,c\}\subset[-1,1]$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{1+a+\frac{7}{9}b^2}\geq3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069951/if-abc-0-and-a-b-c-subset-1-1-so-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt1a-frac7).
Problem 1 can be solved in a similar manner as [Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{8ab+8ac+9bc}{(2b+c)(b+2c)}}\geq5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057006/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt-frac8ab8ac9bc2bcb2c-geq5).
However, it is a computer solution and very complicated.
I want to see if there is nice proofs for problem 1. Also, Problem 1 is verified by *Mathematica*.

The equality cases: $(x, y, z) = (1,1,1), (1,2,0)$.

Any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated.

More details: Problem 1 is equivalent to Problem 2 and Problem 3 as follows.
Problem 3 implies [If $a+b+c=0$ and $\{a,b,c\}\subset[-1,1]$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{1+a+\frac{7}{9}b^2}\geq3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069951/if-abc-0-and-a-b-c-subset-1-1-so-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt1a-frac7)

**Problem 2**: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x + y + z = 3$. Prove that
$$\sqrt{x + \frac{7}{9}(y - 1)^2} + \sqrt{y + \frac{7}{9}(z-1)^2} + \sqrt{z + \frac{7}{9}(x-1)^2} \ge 3.$$

**Problem 3**: Let $a, b, c \ge -1$ with $a + b + c = 0$. Prove that
$$\sqrt{1 + a + \frac{7}{9}b^2} + \sqrt{1 + b + \frac{7}{9}c^2} + \sqrt{1 + c + \frac{7}{9}a^2} \ge 3.$$

Comment: Looks to me Problem 2,3 can be proven using Lagrange Multiplier due to its symmetry.

Comment: @cr001 It is fine if it is simple.